# Gate source voltage of half bridge with bootstrap capacitor incorrect when measured

Tags: buck, voltage-measurement, bootstrap, high-side, low-side

I have a gate driver circuit (Bootstrap capacitor for high side) as in the given diagram.
[image: Gate driver circuit with bootstrap capacitors]

I measured the Vgs for high and low side as shown in the figure below. I get the wrong voltage level for the high and low side Vgs. Since, the gate supply is 12V, Vgs should be 12V rite? When I measure, I get 14.4V for high side and 10V for low side.
[image: Buck converter half-bridge]

The high side Vgs is Red and low side Vgs green.

[image: Vgs for high(red) and low side(green)]

What am I doing wrong? Why do I get wrong Vgs for both high and low side?

Note: There is no load on the half bridge. 48V is is the output voltage of the buck converter. DC Link voltage was 180V.

Comment: What did you probe them with?

Comment: I used one voltage probe for low side. To measure the high side gate source, I measured from Gate to ground and source to ground, and then subtracted.

Comment: And the probes have been checked for compensation and equal gain? -- for example does measuring the source-to-ground voltage with both probes give a correct null result?

Comment: The problem was that the probes were not compensated.